# Sort in descending order using LINQ query syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting

My LINQ sort is working fine (string & date) for asc... I'd like to get it working for desc.  How can I reverse this?  I'm going to be using viewstate to maintain the current sort direction.

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> orderedRows;
 orderedRows = from row in dtValues.AsEnumerable() 
 let title = Convert.ToString(row.Field<string>("TITLE"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
             orderby title
               select row;
 dValues = orderedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add [`descending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx)

```
orderby title descending
```